# Dynamic fields inside JSON object for C3

Tags: spray, spray-json

I am trying to create JSON output in this format for C3 charts =>

```
{
  "data1": [220, 240, 270, 250, 280],
  "data2": [180, 150, 300, 70, 120],
  "data3": [200, 310, 150, 100, 180]
}
```

I can't use normal Scala classes and jsonFormat2 as the names of the fields are dynamic.  I have tried creating a custom RootJsonFormat parser on a simple case class like this =>

```
case class NamedList[Int](name: String, items: Seq[Int])
```

But it did not work since the output required by D3 is a JSON object with values inside it, not a JsArray of name, item pairs.

What is the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been told that this is, of course, a:

```
Map[String, Seq[Int]]
```

Doh!